# Sending sms to mobile phone in C#.net windows application with MTS modem

Tags: c#, windows

This is the code the message box showing ("message sent successfully"). But I didn't get the message to my phone that I used.

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
sp.PortName = "COM4";//choose your port wisely
sp.BaudRate = 9600;
sp.Parity = Parity.None;
sp.Open();
sp.Write("AT+CMGS=\";+91" + textBox1.Text + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
sp.Write(textBox2.Text + (char)26 + Environment.NewLine);
MessageBox.Show("Message sent successfully");
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my code and its worked for me 100% :

```
private SerialPort _serialPort;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string number = textBox1.Text;
        string message = richTextBox1.Text;



        //Replace "COM8"withcorresponding port name
        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM8", 115200);

        Thread.Sleep(100);

        _serialPort.Open();

        Thread.Sleep(100);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");

        Thread.Sleep(100);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + number + "\"\r\n");

        Thread.Sleep(100);

        _serialPort.Write(message + "\x1A");

        Thread.Sleep(300);

        label1.Text = "Message sent !!";

        _serialPort.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Because your using AT&T code to communicate with a device , there should be a brake between every operation .

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code:

```
private void Send()
{
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
    sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);
    sp.PortName = "COM4";//choose your port wisely
    sp.BaudRate = 9600;
    sp.Parity = Parity.None;
    sp.Open();

    // Set the GSM modem to Text Mode
    sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1"+Environment.NewLine);
    // Specifying mobile number
    sp.WriteLine(string.Format("AT+CMGS=\"+91{0}\"{1}", textBox1.Text, Environment.NewLine));
    // Specifying sms body
    sp.WriteLine(textBox2.Text + (char)26 + Environment.NewLine);
    MessageBox.Show("Message sent successfully");
}

private void OnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string modemResult = sp.ReadExisting();
    this.yourTextBox.Text += modemResult;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Dear friend Farzan, thank you for your kind help. but it's not working. the message box showing the message.but didn't get the message to the phone number that i chooses.

Comment: We need to track down the issue, first let's see what is the modem's answer! I have updated the code. Please place a TextBox on your form and set its Multiline property to true then change the code appropriately so that the incoming data will be placed into your TextBox. Try to send the message again and see what is the data shown in textbox, copy the incoming data here if it didn't help you solve the issue.

Comment: hello, do i need to buy a service or anything for this to work? and the serial port is set based on what? sorry for my questions but this is my first time trying to send SMS through code.

Comment: @amateurprogrammer You need to buy a GSM modem which has API documentation for developers and insert a SIM card from a operator of your choice into it. Then u r good to go. Of course a few companies provide API access so you can use their system to send your SMS. This is a better approach if you want to send SMS in Bulk.

Comment: @Farzan thanks a lot, yes I came across the API access and used it and it worked :)

Comment: Yep, am indeed :O

Comment: How to send SMS through my mobile phone instead of GSM Modem? Means I don't want to connect Modem, I want to connect My mobile phone which has a SIM already and has package of SMS.

Comment: @MDSulaiman It depends on the operating system of your phone. If it is an Android phone then you need to write an Android application using Java programming language in Android Studio. There are plenty of good online tutorials available you can google for.

Answer (score -2):

This question bubbled up, so I thought it might be good to answer with an approach that is highly relevant today. As Farzan mentioned in a comment on his answer, there are service providers available that expose APIs which allow you to send SMS messages.  This is even more relevant now as it has become somewhat rare to find landline telephones and even more rare to find a computer with a modem installed.  Twilio is one of the available providers and has made sending an SMS trivial from a development perspective.

```
// Twilio usings
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;

const string accountSid = "your_account_sid"; // specific to your Twilio account
const string authToken = "your_auth_token"; // specific to your Twilion account

TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

// Send a new outgoing SMS by POSTing to the Messages resource
MessageResource.Create(
  from: new PhoneNumber("555-867-5309"), // From number must be an SMS-enabled Twilio number
  to: new PhoneNumber(textBox1.Text),
  body: textBox2.Text);  // Message content

MessageBox.Show("Message sent successfully");
```

Twilio is a subscription service, but they have a "pay as you go" plan that currently costs less than $.01 (US) per message.